How to expand org-mode header variables when tangling in batch mode?
The example given in this previous answer (reproduced below for readability) works well when the file is tangled interactively.
* Test  
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:  :var foo=222
:END:

#+BEGIN_SRC bash :tangle tangle.txt
echo $foo
#+END_SRC

However, when I tangle the file with a batch script, the variable is not expanded.
emacs -Q --batch --eval " (progn (require 'ob-tangle) (dolist (file command-line-args-left) (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file) (org-babel-tangle)))) " test.org
produces a tangle.txt file with:
echo $foo

instead of:
foo='222'
echo $foo

as desired (and obtained when tangling interactively). How to get the interactive behavior with a batch command, since I want to use it in a CI pipeline?

You need to require the babel library for the language. Try this:
 emacs -Q --batch --eval " (progn 
                                 (require 'ob-tangle) 
                                 (require 'ob-shell) 
                                 (dolist (file command-line-args-left) (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file) (org-babel-tangle))))" test.org

With that I get the output from the linked answer:
foo='222'
echo $foo


That works, thank you! A minimal working script is:
emacs -Q --batch --eval " (progn (require 'ob-tangle) (require 'ob-shell) (org-babel-tangle-file \"test.org\")) "
